# Problemas Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando obter algumas informações de uma pagina da Internet e estou usando regex para tal.

Estou utilizando o regex101.com para testar o pattern e consegui chegar a um que me atende perfeitamente. Ocorre que este pattern funciona perfeitamente no regex101.com, mas quando faço a mesma coisa no PHP, não dá nenhum match.

Este é meu código no regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/zgZL8W/2

Veja que são encontradas 7 ocorrências.

Este é o meu código PHP. Apesar de usar o mesmo texto e o mesmo pattern, nenhum match é feito.

```
$pattern = '/<span\>([0-9\/]{10})( {0,})+([A-zÁ-ÿ ]+) {1,}(&#[0-9]{1,6})*[; ]*([0-9]{2}\:{0,}[0-9]{0,2}) +[A-Z]+ +([A-z]{2,}-{0,}[A-z]*)<br \/> <\/span>([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) {0,}[0-9]{1,2} [ A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) +[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) +[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) +[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) +[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) {1,}[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br \/> ([0-9]{1,2}). +([0-9]{1,5}) +[0-9]{1,2} +[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}</';

$mirror = file_get_contents('http://resultadodojogodobicho.deunopostehoje.com/sao-paulo/');

$data = [];

preg_match_all($pattern, $mirror, $data, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($data);
```

Será que alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há dois erros em seu pattern que ao passar para o PHP podem causar esse erro.
O primeiro deles é bem simples.

• Seu código em PHP está sendo tratado com a formatação `ASCII`, e seu texto tem caracteres especiais como `Á`, `É`, etc. e precisa ser tratado como `UTF-8`. Para o compilador corrigir esse erro, você precisará adicionar a flag `/u` em seu regex.

• O outro erro também é apenas uma falta de atenção. Para separar os caracteres brancos do seu pattern, você usou um espaço: . O que pode fazer com que o compilador não identifique-os corretamente dependendo da versão do seu PHP. Esse erro pode ser resolvido com os termos:
`\s` ou `\h`.

**NOTA:**  Não use `\s` nesse caso! O termo pode dar *match* em todos os tipos de caracteres brancos, incluindo quebras de linha (`\n`)! Use `\h` para dar *match* em todos os caracteres de espaço **horizontal**.

**Regex novo:**

```
/<span\>([0-9\/]{10})(\h{0,})+([A-zÁ-ÿ\h]+)\h{1,}(&#[0-9]{1,6})*[;\h]*([0-9]{2}\:{0,}[0-9]{0,2})\h+[A-Z]+\h+([A-z]{2,}-{0,}[A-z]*)<br\h\/>\h<\/span>([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h{0,}[0-9]{1,2}\h[\hA-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h+[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h+[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h+[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h+[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h{1,}[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}<br\h\/>\h([0-9]{1,2}).\h+([0-9]{1,5})\h+[0-9]{1,2}\h+[A-zÁ-ÿ]{4,9}</u
```

**Meu resultado:**

```
C:\wamp64\www\testcode.php:9:
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>12/08/2017 SÁBADO &#8211; 14 HORAS PT-SP<br /> </span>1° 6319  05 Cachorro<br /> 2° 7792  23 Urso<br /> 3° 0978  20 Peru<br /> 4° 0043  11 Cavalo<br /> 5° 8487  22 Tigre<br /> 6° 3619  05 Cachorro<br /> 7° 237  10 Coelho<' (length=242)
      1 => string '12/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'SÁBADO' (length=7)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '14' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PT-SP' (length=5)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '6319' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '7792' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '0978' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '0043' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '8487' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '3619' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '237' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>11/08/2017 SEXTA FEIRA &#8211; 18 HORAS PTN-SP<br /> </span>1° 8116  04 Borboleta<br /> 2° 2115  04 Borboleta<br /> 3° 1720  05 Cachorro<br /> 4° 7308  02 Águia<br /> 5° 2939  10 Coelho<br /> 6° 2198  25 Vaca<br /> 7° 165  17 Macaco<' (length=254)
      1 => string '11/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'SEXTA FEIRA' (length=11)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '18' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PTN-SP' (length=6)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '8116' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '2115' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '1720' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '7308' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '2939' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '2198' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '165' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>11/08/2017 SEXTA FEIRA &#8211; 14 HORAS PT-SP<br /> </span>1° 2254  14 Gato<br /> 2° 0696  24 Veado<br /> 3° 8048  12 Elefante<br /> 4° 5440  10 Coelho<br /> 5° 3019  05 Cachorro<br /> 6° 9457  15 Jacaré<br /> 7° 568  18 Porco<' (length=248)
      1 => string '11/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'SEXTA FEIRA' (length=11)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '14' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PT-SP' (length=5)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '2254' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '0696' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '8048' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '5440' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '3019' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '9457' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '568' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>10/08/2017 QUINTA FEIRA &#8211; 18 HORAS PTN-SP<br /> </span>1° 7961  16 Leão<br /> 2° 9257  15 Jacaré<br /> 3° 6104  01 Avestruz<br /> 4° 0089  23 Urso<br /> 5° 3311  03 Burro<br /> 6° 6722  06 Cabra<br /> 7° 694  24 Veado<' (length=246)
      1 => string '10/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'QUINTA FEIRA' (length=12)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '18' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PTN-SP' (length=6)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '7961' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '9257' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '6104' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '0089' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '3311' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '6722' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '694' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>10/08/2017 QUINTA FEIRA &#8211; 14 HORAS PT-SP<br /> </span>1° 6483  21 Touro<br /> 2° 3411  03 Burro<br /> 3° 8032  08 Camelo<br /> 4° 1259  15 Jacaré<br /> 5° 2156  14 Gato<br /> 6° 1341  11 Cavalo<br /> 7° 113  04 Borboleta<' (length=248)
      1 => string '10/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'QUINTA FEIRA' (length=12)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '14' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PT-SP' (length=5)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '6483' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '3411' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '8032' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '1259' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '2156' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '1341' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '113' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>09/08/2017 QUARTA FEIRA EXTRAÇÃO DAS 13:20 HORAS PT-SP<br /> </span>1• 8222  06 Cabra<br /> 2• 9302  01 Avestruz<br /> 3• 1143  11 Cavalo<br /> 4• 0626  07 Carneiro<br /> 5• 7363  16 Leão<br /> 6• 6656  14 Gato<br /> 7• 481  21 Touro<' (length=264)
      1 => string '09/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'QUARTA FEIRA EXTRAÇÃO DAS' (length=27)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '13:20' (length=5)
      6 => string 'PT-SP' (length=5)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '8222' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '9302' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '1143' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '0626' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '7363' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '6656' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '481' (length=3)
  6 => 
    array (size=21)
      0 => string '<span>08/08/2017 TERÇA FEIRA &#8211; 18 HORAS PTN-SP<br /> </span>1• 3686  22 Tigre<br /> 2• 8315  04 Borboleta<br /> 3• 0928  07  Carneiro<br /> 4• 8461  16 Leão<br /> 5• 6494  24 Veado<br /> 6• 7884  21 Touro<br /> 7• 649  13 Galo<' (length=257)
      1 => string '08/08/2017' (length=10)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string 'TERÇA FEIRA' (length=12)
      4 => string '&#8211' (length=6)
      5 => string '18' (length=2)
      6 => string 'PTN-SP' (length=6)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '3686' (length=4)
      9 => string '2' (length=1)
      10 => string '8315' (length=4)
      11 => string '3' (length=1)
      12 => string '0928' (length=4)
      13 => string '4' (length=1)
      14 => string '8461' (length=4)
      15 => string '5' (length=1)
      16 => string '6494' (length=4)
      17 => string '6' (length=1)
      18 => string '7884' (length=4)
      19 => string '7' (length=1)
      20 => string '649' (length=3)' (length=3)
```

Comment: Legal, Matheus!!! Vou testar e volto aqui pra comentar. Valeu! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)

Comment: Matheus, só tive tempo de testar hoje. Ficou ótimo! Obrigado pelas explicações e pelo código.

Comment: Ah, sem problemas.